# df -ah wrong output - How to correct?

Tags: linux, var, linux-disk-free

[image]

Hello all,

I am unsure why my output for `/dev/mapper/vg_splat-lv_log` is at `84%`.

I used this formula to calculate (Used/Size)x100.

Therefore (270/340)x100 = 79%.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Can this be fixed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [df command not showing correct values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82618/df-command-not-showing-correct-values)